# Mapbox removing symbol from map not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, mapbox-android

I am working on an AndroidApp using the Mapbox integration.
The Issue is, that I call the symbolManager.delete() after onResume() in a Fragment without any error but the symbol is still shown on the map.

I tried much things, like running on UI-Thread, removing it manually from the symbolManager.annotations.remove() but nothing works.

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        fm_main_map?.onResume()
        removeOutdated()
    }

private fun removeOutdated() {
        if (!::symbolManager.isInitialized) return
        val outdatedSymbols = arrayListOf<String>()


        for (item in symbols) {
            Log.d("mappel", "foreach removeOutdated")
            val cloudO = itemsInRange[item.key]

            if (cloudO?.second?.endsWithStamp ?: 0 < MyTimeApiin .millisNow() {
                symbolManager.delete(item.value)
                itemsInRange.remove(item.key)
                outdatedSymbols.add(item.key)
            }
        }

        symbolManager.updateSource()

        outdatedSymbols.forEach {
            symbols.remove(it)
        }

    }
```

Don't know what to do.
Working on this issue for 3 days now and google does not give any results.